# Proper syntax for escaping a `$` in a regex in a bash shell script/makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regex, makefile

I'm running a `Makefile` which includes the following line...

```
find ./ -type f -regextype emacs -regex ".*tests$" | xargs rm -f
```

and am getting an error:

```
find ./ -type f -regextype emacs -regex ".*tests | xargs rm -f
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I did a Google search for correct ways to escape; none of the escape-syntaxes which I came across seem to work (i.e., using single quotes, using a single back-slash, using a double-backslash).

Am running bash on LXDE (Ubuntu 14.04).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make is swallowing the dollar sign.  Try `find ./ -type f -regextype emacs -regex ".*tests$$" | xargs rm -f`.  See [Escaping in makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile)

Comment: OK. Answer added.

Comment: great that you chose to add comprehensive answer; though i would've clicked accept had you simply copy-pasted your comment!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I really didn't want to get my head around Makefile escaping followed by shell escaping followed by regex escaping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

Compare the line in the `makefile`:

```
find ./ -type f -regextype emacs -regex ".*tests$" | xargs rm -f
```

With the line in the error message:

```
find ./ -type f -regextype emacs -regex ".*tests | xargs rm -f
```

It appears that `make` swallowed `$"`.

#### The solution

To avoid this, the dollar sign needs to be escaped.  Try:

```
find ./ -type f -regextype emacs -regex ".*tests$$" | xargs rm -f
```

#### Documentation

From the [GNU Make Manual Section 4.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax):

> Because dollar signs are used to start make variable references, if
>   you really want a dollar sign in a target or prerequisite you must
>   write two of them, ‘$$’ (see How to Use Variables). If you have
>   enabled secondary expansion (see Secondary Expansion) and you want a
>   literal dollar sign in the prerequisites list, you must actually write
>   four dollar signs (‘$$$$’).